# DateTime plus Period shows incorrect timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Joda DateTime API returns date with incorrect timezone after **plus** operation. 
Below is the code:

```
Interval interval = new Interval("2011-03-21/2011-10-31", ISOChronology.getInstance(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Prague")));
Period period = Period.weeks(1);

DateTime start = interval.getStart();
DateTime end = start.plus(period);
```

And in the debug mode, I see:

```
interval = "2011-03-21T00:00:00.000+01:00/2011-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00"
start = "2011-03-21T00:00:00.000+01:00"
end = "2011-03-28T00:00:00.000+02:00"
```

As you can see, **interval** has **+01:00** for start and end.
but **end** shows **+02:00** after **plus** operation.

How to do **plus(Period)** and keep zone ?

Comment: Is there a daylights savings time switchover between 3/21 and 3/28?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 27/03/2011 the daylight time change occurred...

edit: written wrong year :P

Comment: oh, you are right, I did not think about daylight time change.
With other month everything works. Thanks !!!